# source-specific multicast using boost

Tags: c++, boost, udp, boost-asio, multicast

How can I join source-specific multicast (ssm) group using boost?

I'v successfully joined any-source multicast group using

`set_option( ip::multicast::join_group( mcAddr.to_v4(), ifAddr.to_v4( )));`

but I have no idea how to set ssm (`IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`).

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you will have to implement their [`SettableSocketOption`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSocketOption.html) concept. Checking out how existing multicast options are done ([svn link](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/ip/detail/socket_option.hpp)) might help.

Comment: Tried to open the link and got "This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested" error

Answer (score 3):

yes. I use this

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class add_source_membership_v4
// is for Windows Sockets 2 IPv4
// to set IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP option.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class add_source_membership_v4
{
private:
    ip_mreq_source ipv4_value_{};

public:
    // Default constructor.
    // Construct with multicast address and IPv4 address specifying an interface.
    add_source_membership_v4(
        const boost::asio::ip::address_v4& multicast_address,
        const boost::asio::ip::address_v4& source_address,
        const boost::asio::ip::address_v4& network_interface = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any())
    {
        ipv4_value_.imr_multiaddr.s_addr =
            boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long(
                multicast_address.to_uint());
        ipv4_value_.imr_sourceaddr.s_addr =
            boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long(
                source_address.to_uint());
        ipv4_value_.imr_interface.s_addr =
            boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long(
                network_interface.to_uint());
    }

    // Returns a value suitable for passing as the level argument to POSIX setsockopt() (or equivalent).
    template <typename Protocol>
    int level(const Protocol&) const noexcept
    {
        return BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF(IPPROTO_IP);
    }

    // Returns a value suitable for passing as the option_name argument to POSIX setsockopt() (or equivalent).
    template <typename Protocol>
    int name(const Protocol&) const noexcept
    {
        return IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP;
    }

    // Returns a pointer suitable for passing as the option_value argument to POSIX setsockopt() (or equivalent).
    template <typename Protocol>
    const void* data(const Protocol&) const noexcept
    {
        return &ipv4_value_;
    }

    // Returns a value suitable for passing as the option_len argument to POSIX setsockopt() (or equivalent),
    // after appropriate integer conversion has been performed.
    template <typename Protocol>
    std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const noexcept
    {
        return sizeof(ipv4_value_);
    }
};
```